# Categories overlaps when export the chart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have this chart: http://jsfiddle.net/pLDeq/10/

```
exporting: {
    enabled: true,
    exportButton: {
        enabled: true
    },
    buttons: {
        customButton: {
            symbol: 'url(http://cdn1.iconfinder.com/data/icons/fatcow/16/chart_bar.png)',
            onclick: function() {
                setChartColumn([name,name2], categories, [data,data2], ['column','column']); 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the jsFiddle the chart exports correctly but in my project looks like this:
[image]

What could be the problem? I'm using the same scripts.

Comment: Could you post link to your website? Are you sure you have latest version of Highcharts and exporting?

Comment: I can't cause is in the internal network, and yep I'm sure. Could be a conflict with something? This is the code that generates: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3375

Comment: Are you sure that you are using the same version of jquery and the other libraries?

Comment: Pretty sure: http://codeviewer.org/view/code:3375

Comment: Which browser? Also, are you using Highcharts exporting server or your own? Maybe you are using some CSS styles on chart which aren't exported.

Comment: IE 8, but I check in IE10 and its the same problem, I'm using the default exporting server. That could be a problem with CSS then?

Comment: I think that issue may be connected to this ticket: https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/818 but still, without reproduced issue I can't help with that. Maybe you could try to setup your own exporting server, to make sure you have latest one?

Comment: Have you tried specifying a fixed export size with `exporting.sourceHeight` and `exporting.sourcewidth`? Say, to 1024x768 or bigger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this as a solution and work:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8" />
```